# How do I ask for user input until the user stops?

Tags: python

**The Question**
Write a program that reads a list of integers into a list as long as the integers are greater than zero, then outputs the smallest and largest integers in the list.

Ex: If the input is:
10
5
3
21
2
-6 (negative six, the format is weird on stackoverflow)

the output is:
2
21

You can assume that the list of integers will have at least 2 values.

**My Code**

```
lst =[]

for i in range(6):
    if i > 0:
        i = int(input())
        lst.append(i)

print (min(lst), max(lst))
```

**The Problem**
My code works perfectly well for the example input given where there are 6 inputs. However, for a different number of inputs (such as 4 inputs or 9 inputs), the range(6) is limited and doesn't produce the output that I want. I just don't know how I'm supposed to determine the range for asking the input when *The Question* doesn't specify the number of intputs it will take in.

**Code after Help**

```
lst =[]

while True:
  _input= int(input())
  if _input < 0:
    break
  lst.append(_input)

print(min(lst),max(lst))
```

Comment: I think the question meant as long as the input  integers are  > 0, not range `i > 0`

Comment: @hippozhipos Yeah you're right. I changed it so that _input=int(input()) is before the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could you `while` operator and `break`

```
lst = []
while True:
    _input = int(input())
    if _input < 0:
        break
    lst.append(_input)
```

Or if you use python3.8 it could be even prettier:

```
lst = []
while _input := int(input()) >= 0:
    lst.append(_input)
```

Comment: Ohhhh, I see!! So it just asks an input until the input is negative. I thought it could keep asking even after a negative value has been taken in as the input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
user_num = int(input())
list_num = []

while user_num > 0:
    list_num.append(user_num)
    user_num = int(input())

print(min(list_num),'and',max(list_num))
```

Comment: I'm currently taking course IFT 101: Info. Tech. Programming and just got this question. I know this is not perfect code but it worked for me. hope this helps the next person.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more flexible program for future expandability, you can implement a generator function for use in list comprehension. An example of what that might look like is this:

```py
# Future imports (needed for certain type hinting functionality)
from __future__ import annotations

# Standard library imports
from re import compile as re_compile
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

# Type checking (this is False during runtime)
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from re import Pattern
    from typing import Generator


def int_input_generator() -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    """Integer generator: Stops generating when given incorrect input"""
    numbers_only: Pattern = re_compile(r'^-?[0-9]+$')
    user_input: str
    int_input: int

    while numbers_only.match((user_input := input())) is not None \
            and (int_input := int(user_input)) > 0:
        yield int_input
    return


def main() -> None:
    """Main function to run the program"""
    input_list: list[int] = [_ for _ in int_input_generator()]

    if input_list:
        print(f'{min(input_list)}\n{max(input_list)}')
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I went ahead and type hinted the code for better understanding. Also, the `int_input_generator` takes care of cases when the input is not a number.

*Note: I opted for using regex for numeric validation since functions like `str.isnumeric()`, `str.isdecimal()`, and `str.isdigit()` allow for certain unicode characters that are not the typical ASCII digits.*

Answer (score -1):

this got me 10\10

```py
user_numbers = []
user_input = int(input())
while user_input > 0:
   user_numbers.append(user_input)
   user_input = int(input())
print(user_numbers)
```